# How to install qt libraries in Qt creator in windows?

Tags: c++, string, qt, qt-creator, qr-code

I am trying to install qren libraries in Qt creator to generate a QR code from a string.

I tried downloading the git repo but it is not working. After downloading the git repo there is no lib files to choose in Qt creator. So how do I can install the required libraries in Qt and use it for my purpose?

The git repo that i am using:https://github.com/fukuchi/libqrencode

Qt creator image
[Next option is not enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v886h.png)

Comment: Have you tried actually building the library, or installing it using vcpkg?

Comment: There should almost never be lib files in a github repository. A repository is supposed to be for source code. And in many cases it's supposed to allow anyone to build on many different operating systems instead of providing binaries that are only  good for one of these.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are misunderstanding how repositories work. What you are looking for is a binary. A repository rarely (and shouldn't) contain binaries, but rather the source code from which you can build said binaries.

Looking at the repository that you linked, there are multiple ways of getting said binaries.

1. Build them yourself using CMake; you will find the instruction inside the README of the repository.
2. Install it using vcpkg; the instructions are once again found in the README of the repository.

vcpkg instructions from the repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
cd vcpkg
./bootstrap-vcpkg.sh
./vcpkg integrate install
./vcpkg install libqrencode
```

If you are working on Windows, using vcpkg is most likely the most painless way of getting the binaries you want.

Comment: On a related note, with C++ libraries different compilers require different binary library files. _This is a C library, so this is not an issue_, but it's something to be aware of when using 3rd party libs.